# Why does the following thing happen?

Tags: optics

Once I was recording a video of things passing by me while travelling by a car .I noticed that closer things such as the road appeared blurr but the farther objects were clearly visible in the video.Why did this happen?

Comment: Just a question of focus... What is it that you don't fully understand?

Comment: The rate of angular change is much higher for near objects vs. far away objects.  If the camera is pointed at a particular far away object while you are moving at a constant velocity, all objects closer than a certain distance, which depends on your velocity and the camera shutter speed, will be blurry due to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Each image, taken in a video, needs an exposure time to exposure the pixels in the camera. Now, an edge, close to you, gets shifted during the exposure time some pixels to the right (or left, depends from the direction of your motion). An edge, far away, moves slower through your image and the pixel shift is less than for closer to you things.

BTW, at the beginning of photography the emulsion on the film needed a very long exposure time (1 minute or even longer) and if the people on that image have moved an arm or the face, they were blurry on this photo.

In Wikipedia read about [motion blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur).